# How to render different view based on screen size

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I render different view on same project based on screen size?
I have two views which are using the same controller. I need to show different view based on screen size. 
When the user reduce the browser screen size to some particular px(say x px) or browse from mobile it should render view2. If the browser size is greater than x px it should render view2. Both view functionalities are same and have to use same controller action. But render different view based on screen size. Is it Possible? If so how can I achieve this?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use two views. if you write, you must write two views for every views (phone views and pc views, later tablet views or any size of views...). You can write css for this functionality or use any css framework to do this. for example [twitter-bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).

**[CSS FRAMEWORK EXAMPLES](http://mashable.com/2013/04/26/css-boilerplates-frameworks/)**

Comment: Out client need some UI changes for mobile view. So we must have two different views but functionalities are same. So we have to use the same controller action. How can I get this?

Comment: You can handle screen size with jquery. And pass parameter to controller that represent your view type and load or redirect to view that you need.

Comment: Is it possible to use same controller action for multiple views?